# Is there GUI Scala Console that I can download and run from command line?

Tags: user-interface, scala

Groovy has a nice GUI Console in which I can enter any java/groovy code and run.
This is distributed with groovy.

As for as I know Scala does not have anything like that except for REPL.

Is there any third party Scala GUI Console that I can download and install and run from command line and not from a JNLP file using webstart?

One use case:

Suppose I have Scala program:

```
val lineWidth = 2.5
val axisWidth = 1.5
val white = ConstVec3(1)
val background = white
val axisColor = ConstVec3(0)

drawFunction("Plot") { (dims, pixel) =>
  val mid = dims/2.0
  val p = pixel - mid

  val color: Vec3 = background

  color *= {
    val shade = clamp(abs(p.x)/axisWidth, 0, 1)
    mix(axisColor, background, shade)
  }
  color *= {
    val shade = clamp(abs(p.y)/axisWidth, 0, 1)
    mix(axisColor, background, shade)
  }

  color *= {
    val scale = 2/mid.x

    val x = p.x*scale
    val y = p.y*scale

    val f = smoothstep(-1, 1, x)
    val shade = clamp(abs(f - y)/(scale*lineWidth), 0, 1)
    mix(Vec3(1, 0, 0), Vec3(1), shade)
  }

  color
}
```

In Groovy Console (which is a full blown GUI) I can easily copy and paste above program. I can easily modify the program in GUI and quickly hit the run button and quickly see the result. I can even easily copy and paste the results and post it somewhere else. I can easily copy lines of Scala code from somewhere else and copy into GUI Console and hit the run button and I can also copy certain jars into a location that is in the classpath of Groovy Console and so on and on long list of lot more features.

Can you do that in REPL or is there another tool you can use?

Comment: Why you think REPL is pathetic ??? I really don't see the need of a GUI to evaluate expressions interactively. What can you do in your Groovy console GUI that you can't do with the Scala REPL ?

Comment: Actually, you can start REPL from the command line. Just type `scala`. If you want to have any other features that require a GUI and cannot be done on a text-only console, please specify in your question what features you are missing in REPL.

Comment: -1 for calling the REPL pathetic. I'd like to see you write something better.

Comment: The Groovy Console is not really a console: So you are more looking for a minimalistic IDE, aren't you?

Comment: Most of things you say you can do in Groovy Console can also be done in Scala REPL.

Comment: @ericacm - There are such things, and they're easy to get; they just aren't included with the standard distribution.  I think if amc had spent a quarter the time looking for one as writing that post, he or she would have found one.  Googling "gui front end scala REPL" provides two different alternatives in the top three hits and a third one a little further down.

Comment: Cool - it would be nice if something like one of these was included with the Scala distro.

Comment: @ericacm - Eh, the Scala distro is large enough for me already.  Maybe these should be linked more clearly e.g. from the download page.

Comment: Voted to close because not constructive. Please leave derogatory opinions out of your question.

Comment: Actually, it is utterly irrelevant whether REPL is "pathetic" or not. That is a pejorative term which is bound to draw emotive discussion -- as can be clearly seen. Also, you do not have a _right_ to post your opinions here -- much on the contrary, questions should stick to facts. These rules exist to keep things civil and draw a community of quality. By needlessly insulting a tool instead of keeping to the facts you gained nothing and hurt Stack Overflow a little bit. In the future, please keep your opinions to yourself, and do not draw the ire of those who would help you.

Comment: As a side note, the question is valid and there are plenty answers to it. I'd rather not close it -- just downvote it to its rightful place.

Comment: Actually, the Scala REPL was once quite pathetic, but thanks to the hard work of unnamed invidual(s), it is now quite useful. Try asking for the type of an expression in your Groovy REPL -- won't happen will it? Being able to formally reason about code, in such a way as to have machine-checked verification, is vastly superior than cracking the cowboy whip in my opinion.

Enjoy that GUI dude.

Comment: Looks like it's been done as part of the new Scala IDE: http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/Run_Selection_Interpreter

Comment: The new IntelliJ (11) Scala plugin has a fully featured REPL/editor.  http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/10/19/scala-language-console-nika-builds/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the kind of exploratory coding that you're talking about, you should check out [Kojo](http://www.kogics.net/sf:kojo).  Just ignore the parts designed for teaching children how to program (e.g. drag the border between the turtle window and the rest until it's as small as it can get), and you find that you have a full-fledged GUI with syntax highlighting and everything that lets you run code with a press of a button (or two presses of the keyboard).  Or maybe you want to use the turtle to do the drawing, given the example you gave.

You might also be interested in [ScalaConsole](https://bitbucket.org/centaur/scalaconsole/wiki/Home) or [Scalide](http://code.google.com/p/scalide/wiki/Home).

Comment: Agreed, ScalaConsole is exactly what he is looking for.  It is derived from the Groovy Console.

Comment: The ScalaIDE now has the Scala Worksheet bundled.   Check it out, it's really nice.  https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started.   It is featured prominently in the Coursera course "Functional Programming Principles in Scala": https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun

Answer (score 2):

You definitely looking for an [Integrated Development Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

There is plugin for theses IDE:

- [Eclipse](http://www.scala-ide.org/)
- [IntelliJ IDEA](http://plugins.jetbrains.net/plugin/?id=1347)

My personal favourite is using a simple text editor with [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki), you can use for example:

- [VIM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3524)
- [Emacs](http://scala.sygneca.com/tools/emacs)

Comment: And both IDEA and Eclipse got some REPL integration.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it is worth, if you don't want to try out swing stuff, you might even go with [Simply Scala](http://www.simplyscala.com/).